# Component not rendering Image as expected in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on the profile picture for my app for which I have designed a custom reusable component called `ProfilePhoto`. I am using that component in the `Profile` parent screen as seen below in my code.
Initially, no profile picture is selected from the gallery and nothing renders, which is fine. But after I have selected an image from the gallery (to prove that I log the path) it's not appearing in the component as expected.

My code:

```js
//Parent - Profile Screen
class ProfileScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('PROFILE SCREEN');
    console.log(auth().currentUser);

    this.state = {
      image: {
        uri: null, //' '
        width: null,
        height: null,
        mime: null,
      },
    };
  }

  renderImage(image) {
    return <ProfilePhoto diameter={228} borderWidth={5} image={image} />; //Custom Component
  }

  pickSingleWithCamera(cropping, mediaType = 'photo') {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      cropping: cropping,
      width: 228,
      height: 228,
      includeExif: true,
      mediaType,
      cropperCircleOverlay: true,
    })
      .then(image => {
        console.log('received image', image);
        console.log('image path: ', image.path);
        this.setState({
          image: {
            uri: image.path,
            width: image.width,
            height: image.height,
            mime: image.mime,
          },
          images: null,
        });
      })
      .then(async () => {
        console.log('Uploading...');
        this.uploadImage(this.state.image.uri);
      })
      .catch(e => alert(e));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
          <View>
            {this.state.image ? this.renderImage(this.state.image) : null}
          </View>
          <Button
            title="Pick Image"
            onPress={() => this.pickSingleWithCamera(true)}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default ProfileScreen;
```

```js
//Custom Component - ProfilePhoto
class ProfilePhoto extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.diameter = this.props.diameter;
    this.borderWidth = this.props.borderWidth;
    this.image = this.props.image || null;
    console.log('image: ', this.image);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: this.diameter,
          height: this.diameter,
          borderRadius: this.diameter / 2,
          borderWidth: this.borderWidth,
          borderColor: '#00A1ED',
          shadowColor: '#00A1ED67',
          shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 7},
          shadowRadius: 6,
        }}>
        <Image
          source={this.image}
          style={{
            width: this.diameter,
            height: this.diameter,
            borderRadius: this.diameter / 2,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ProfilePhoto;
```

My logs:

```
//Initial Log
image:  {"height": null, "mime": null, "uri": null, "width": null}
//After Picking image
 image:  {"height": 228, "mime": "image/jpeg", "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/e56f5507-3e45-409d-990f-c88812ff2c4b.jpg", "width": 228}
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the correct image attributes in Profile component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `this.renderImage(this.state.image.uri)` instead of `this.renderImage(this.state.image)`?

The `source` part of the RN `<Image/>` tag should be a uri instead of an object.

---

After changing the stuff mentioned above, `this.props.image` in your your ProfilePhoto Component should be a uri that can be `null` or a `string`. Now try:

```
<Image
  source={this.props.image? this.props.image : null}
  style={{
     width: this.diameter,
     height: this.diameter,
     borderRadius: this.diameter / 2,
  }}
/>
```

and remove `this.image = this.props.image || null;` in the constructor

---

**Update:** Glad it works, updating the reason here for easier reading to any potential reader

The reason is that `this.props.image` is re-assigned to a local variable `this.image`, since the UI is depended on `this.image`, which is not `state` / `props`, it won't reflect to any changes of the image source

Comment: What's `rendering()` in `ProfilePhoto` used for? I don't see anywhere calling it.

Comment: Thats useless, sorry

Comment: If you directly put that path `"file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/e56f5507-3e45-409d-990f-c88812ff2c4b.jpg"` into the `image` source tag, does it show the image?

Comment: @yashatreya Just thought of something, please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks it worked. Trrying to award you the bounty but it says it, I can award it to you in 22 hours

Comment: The reason is that you assign your `this.props.image` to a local variable `this.image`, and your UI is depended on `this.image`, which is not `state` / `props` so it won't reflect to any changes of your image source, glad it helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

try:
`source={{ uri: this.image.uri }}`